# Can't find Namespace in Solution with multiple Project with same Namespace

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, namespaces

I got the following Solution:
There is a Shared Project with a class:

```
namespace Xamarin.Forms.Lib.Controlls
public class A{
}
```

And I got an Android Project where I also got the Namespace `namespace Xamarin.Forms.Lib`

Now when I want to consume the `class A` in the Andorid Project I got the error, that the namespace could not be found. 
I am wondering why... it drives me crazy.

Here the exact errormessage if you understand german:

```
C:\Development\Git\Dev\Lib\Xamarin.Forms.Lib\src\Xamarin.Forms.Lib.Test
\Xamarin.Forms.Lib.Test.Android\MainActivity.cs(9,25,9,34): error CS0234:
Der Typ- oder Namespacename "Controlls" ist im Namespace
"Xamarin.Forms.Lib" nicht vorhanden. (Möglicherweise fehlt ein 
Assemblyverweis.)
```

It would be nice if anyone got an answer for that problem.
Notice that the share project is an .netstandard 2.0 and the android project is mono71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the problem with the same namespaces, your Android project's name space is `Xamarin.Forms.Lib`, which is conflict with the package's namespace of official  Xamarin.Forms.

So if you try to create a Xamarin.Android project for example named "Test.Android" and then create a shared project named "Test.Android.Controls", and correctly add reference, you will find that it's able to find class A under shared project from your Android project as normal.

I suggest to change the namespace of your project.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I was thinking about that problem with the namespace `Xamarin.Froms.Lib`before, but I though it won't matter... wrong! ^^